# differentiable functions, concave or convex?

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

Suppose U and g are two twice differentiable functions of x, both of them increasing and concave, with U’ ≥ 0, U” ≤ 0, g’ ≥ 0, and g” ≤ 0. Prove that the composite function f(x) = g(U(x)) is also increasing and concave.

i am pretty stuck on this and have no idea where to start or what it should look like, all help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: try using the chain rule: $f^\prime(x) = U^\prime(x)g^\prime(U(x))$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the chain rule on the sets where it has sense : you will have that $$f'=U'\cdot g'(U)\geq 0$$ by hypothesis, and $$f''=U''\cdot g'(U)+(U')^2\cdot g''(U)\leq 0,$$ giving you that $f$ is increasing and concave.